# Importing BitTorrent bencode module

Tags: python, macos, egg

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6. Python is 2.6.1.
I've installed bencode module as

> sudo easy_install BitTorrent-bencode

It appeared in site-packages

> /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg

But, how to import and use this module?

```
>>> import bencode
```

doesn't work...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bencode
```

How to import modules from site-packages?
How to recognize module name BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg contains?

> > > sys.path
> > >       ['', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i see, BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.4.egg on pypi does not containt bencode.py.
I would download [sources](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/BitTorrent-bencode/BitTorrent-bencode-5.0.8.tar.gz#md5=5ad77003d18fc2e698d8d0d83be78d11) and manually copy bencode.py and BTL.py in your site-packages folder.

Comment: Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from BitTorrent.bencode import bencode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named BitTorrent.bencode

:-(

Comment: i was changing my answer because i tried on Osx using pip and i got the same error.I've tried to dezip .egg and i did not found sources.

Answer (score 2):

The BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.4.egg is broken.  If you use unzip to look at the contents of the egg you'll see:

```
$ unzip BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Archive:  BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg
  inflating: EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt  
  inflating: EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO       
  inflating: EGG-INFO/SOURCES.txt    
  inflating: EGG-INFO/top_level.txt  
  inflating: EGG-INFO/zip-safe       
  inflating: test/__init__.py        
  inflating: test/__init__.pyc       
  inflating: test/benchmarkbencode.py  
  inflating: test/benchmarkbencode.pyc  
  inflating: test/benchmarkdata.py   
  inflating: test/benchmarkdata.pyc  
  inflating: test/testbencode.py     
  inflating: test/testbencode.pyc
```

Notice that bencode.py and BTL.py are not included.  If you download the source distribution for the package from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/BitTorrent-bencode/BitTorrent-bencode-5.0.8.tar.gz#md5=5ad77003d18fc2e698d8d0d83be78d11), you can get the missing files.  The problem with the package is that the setup.py does not include the root directory of the distribution in the list of packages that the egg is created by.  To fix this you could edit setup.py and replace the line that says:

```
     packages = find_packages(),
```

with:

```
     packages = ['','test'],
```

Then, running `python setup.py install` will correctly install the package.

Comment: OK, thanks! Actually, I already copied bencode.py and BTL.py to site-packages manually.

Comment: That's still not correct, anyway -- the correct entry would be 'py_modules = "bencode"', with the 'packages' line removed altogether.

Answer (score 2):

use pip install bencode.py

rather than pip install bencode

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use the `bzrlib.bencode` package. This installs with `easy_install` or `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to add the .egg to `sys.path`. The easiest way to do *that* is to drop a .pth file into `site-packages/` containing the filename of the egg:

`BitTorrent_bencode.pth`:

```
BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg
```

If it still doesn't import properly at this point then you may have the module or package name wrong. Open the .egg file in something that can open .zip files and examine the internal structure for hints.

Comment: There is already easy-install.pth that contains
"import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./BitTorrent_bencode-5.0.8-py2.6.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)"

Is this enough?

Comment: Sure. In which case you should proceed with the rest of my answer. If *that* also produces no results then the egg itself is broken, and you should notify upstream about this.