# HTTP request to the torrent tracker in python

Tags: python, torrent

I want to write a python torrent client (because I need it and I want to improve my skills).
I have to send a HTTP get request to the tracker. I'm using the requests library.

```
from read_torrent import *
import requests as req


txt = read_torrent('arch.torrent')
(res, other) = parse(txt)
pl = {}
pl['uploaded'] = 0
pl['downloaded'] = 0
pl['event'] = 'started'
pl['peer_id'] = '12345678987654321234'
pl['info_hash'] = dont_know
pl['left'] = 0
pl['port'] = 6881

r = requests.get(res['announce'], params=pl)
r.raise_for_status()
print('-------RESULT-------')
print(r.text)
```

Two questions:

1. Am I using the `get` function in the right way?
2. What shuld I use as `info_hash`?

Ps. I've already read [THIS](http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html#anchor18) and the wiki theory page.

Comment: The link may be valid today, but will probably become useless in a few weeks. Please post a code sample to illustrate your question instead of redirecting on a github repository

Comment: This might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The info_hash is a SHA1 hash which you compute from the .torrent file. (bencoded info dictionary). An example for Python can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173411/3606329).

The get request should contain at first the link of the HTTP-Tracker + structure for the announce request.

Please note: most trackers are nowadays UDP (less overhead). You must make sure that your .torrent file contains a HTTP-tracker (open the file in an editor). Trackers starting with udp:// will not give you a response to your HTTP-request.