# Convert python2 script to python3

Tags: python

Would like to get this script working with python3 (Python 3.10.4):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573715/2394635

It would be where it says **Full code bellow:**

I don't put the code directly because I get the stackoverflow notification `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

I've used the pip script `2to3`, with this resulting code:

```
import sys, os, hashlib, io, bencode

def pieces_generator(info):
    """Yield pieces from download file(s)."""
    piece_length = info['piece length']
    if 'files' in info: # yield pieces from a multi-file torrent
        piece = ""
        for file_info in info['files']:
            path = os.sep.join([info['name']] + file_info['path'])
            print(path)
            sfile = open(path.decode('UTF-8'), "rb")
            while True:
                piece += sfile.read(piece_length-len(piece))
                if len(piece) != piece_length:
                    sfile.close()
                    break
                yield piece
                piece = ""
        if piece != "":
            yield piece
    else: # yield pieces from a single file torrent
        path = info['name']
        print(path)
        sfile = open(path.decode('UTF-8'), "rb")
        while True:
            piece = sfile.read(piece_length)
            if not piece:
                sfile.close()
                return
            yield piece

def corruption_failure():
    """Display error message and exit"""
    print("download corrupted")
    exit(1)

def main():
    # Open torrent file
    torrent_file = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
    metainfo = bencode.bdecode(torrent_file.read())
    info = metainfo['info']
    pieces = io.StringIO(info['pieces'])
    # Iterate through pieces
    for piece in pieces_generator(info):
        # Compare piece hash with expected hash
        piece_hash = hashlib.sha1(piece).digest()
        if (piece_hash != pieces.read(20)):
            corruption_failure()
    # ensure we've read all pieces 
    if pieces.read():
        corruption_failure()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, keeps failing:

```
% python3 extract-torrent.py archive.torrent 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smt/Documents/extract-torrent-py3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sys, os, hashlib, io, bencode
  File "/home/smt/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bencode.py", line 73, in <module>
    from types import StringType, IntType, LongType, DictType, ListType, TupleType
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringType' from 'types' (/usr/lib/python3.10/types.py)
```

Any help?

Comment: You're importing a package or module, `bencode`, that is not Python 3.10 compatible. That is causing your error. Given that that package latest release dates from 2010, that is not surprising. Note that the linked answer (& code) is also from 2010.

Comment: @9769953 thanks a lot, with `python2` it works. I had to install `python-pip` instead of default `python3-pip` to get it working, also run `pip2 install bencode`.

Answer (score 1):

As @9769953 pointed out, `bencode` is not compatible with Python 3.10. You could try `bencodepy` which [claims](https://pypi.org/project/bencode.py/) to be compatible with both Python 2 and 3.

From the [website](https://pypi.org/project/bencode.py/):

1. Install with `pip install bencode.py`
2. Import with `import bencodepy`

Comment: `bencodepy` does not work straightforward, however the `python2` version work, however it only test if hash matches for those files from the torrent that are already downloaded, otherwise throws error.